OpenIA deployment with bicep
Im trying to deploy the OpenAI resurce in North Europe but I get below error

Exception Details:  (InvalidApiSetId) The account type 'OpenAI' is
either invalid or unavailable in given region.        Code: InvalidApiSetId
Message: The account type 'OpenAI' is either invalid or unavailable
in given region.

Is it not available in northeurope or my api is not working? Belo is my code which worked 2 weeks ago for Westeurope region
param openAIAccountName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location

param privatesubnetId string
param publicsubnetId string
param IPRules array

resource openAIAccount 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts@2024-04-01-preview' = {
  name: openAIAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'S0'
  }
  kind: 'OpenAI'
  properties: {
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    customSubDomainName: openAIAccountName
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        {
          id: privatesubnetId
        }
        {
          id:publicsubnetId
        }
      ]
      ipRules: [
        for ip in IPRules: {
          value: ip
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource gpt3_5 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/deployments@2024-04-01-preview' = {
  parent: openAIAccount
  name: 'gpt35Endpoint'
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
    capacity: 120
  }
  properties: {
    model: {
      format: 'OpenAI'
      name: 'gpt-35-turbo'
      version: '0301'
    }
    versionUpgradeOption: 'OnceNewDefaultVersionAvailable'
    currentCapacity: 120
    raiPolicyName: 'Microsoft.Default'
  }
}


For the selected open AI sku seems not supporting for the mentioned location can you please change the location that supports the sku you trying to deploy @play_something_good

well, I need to keep the region northeurope. Where  can I find the supported SKU's per region?

check this https://openaidiscovery.com/blog/openai-api-key-not-working/#:~:text=This%20error%20is%20very%20easy%20to%20fix%2C%20you,Review%20and%20adjust%20the%20key%E2%80%99s%20permissions%20as%20needed for troubleshoot steps to check the possiblilities if you definetly want that partcular region

to check the list of skus available for the particular region run the command
az cognitiveservices account list-skus --location "northeurope" -o table
this will listout the availability of the skus as per the region mentioned

Region limitation is seems to be the issue when i change region it works seemlessly refer image

I also dont see any region named north europe while creating OpenAI model in the portal seems youre specifing the region with the incorrect value refer: image

if you see my location variable is same as RG location which is deployed in northeurope with other resource. Above bicep code is small part of full code where I also deploy KV, ST etc. and each of them are deployed in northeurope using same location variable

every resource can be created as they dont have any limitations the issue arises when we try to provision openai when i try select a region from the drop down its not showing any option related to north europe i only find west europe and northen part of eruppe while creating an open ai it divided into some new region with different names @playsomethinggood


OpenAI deployment with bicep

After running through multiple case I was able to figure out the issue. It seems to be the use of region name northeurope
While achieving the same in the portal I came to know that there is only one key word which matches europe is while using west Europe
Go to the portal and see the list of regions available to deploy the model that is avaialble nearby north europe
i.e., France Central,Germany West Central,Norwayeast,Poland Central,Spain Central,Sweden Central,Switzerland North,Switzerland West,UK South,west europe
these regions are specifically for the europe based on the availablity and quota

Demo configruation:
resource openAIAccount 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts@2024-04-01-preview' = {
  name: openAIAccountName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'S0'
  }
  kind: 'OpenAI'
  properties: {
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    customSubDomainName: openAIAccountName
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        {
          id: virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[0].id
        }
      ]
      ipRules: [
        for ip in ipRules: {
          value: ip
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource openAIDeployment 'Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/deployments@2024-04-01-preview' = {
  parent: openAIAccount
  name: deploymentName
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard'
    capacity: modelCapacity
  }
  properties: {
    model: {
      format: 'OpenAI'
      name: modelName
      version: modelVersion
    }
    versionUpgradeOption: 'OnceNewDefaultVersionAvailable'
    currentCapacity: modelCapacity
    raiPolicyName: 'Microsoft.Default'
  }
}

Here i tried deployement using France Central region situated in northen part of europe or nearer to it and my RG was north europe
deployment:


refer:
Create an Azure AI services resource using Bicep - Azure AI services | Microsoft Learn
Info related to quota can be refered here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/quotas-limits

which model did you deploy? I have tried to deploy gpt turbo 35 and seems like its not supported in swedencentral :/

There might be quota issue with your subscription for that location select one from the list I shared that has limit available for your subscription like i did using France central @play_something_good

version was the issue, i had to swtich to 1106
